# Why the Divergence of Electric field is Zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, non-linear-optics

I am studying nonlinear optics, specifically the wave equation of nonlinear optical media.
During the derivation I came across a point where the divergence of electric field was zero for a linear isotropic medium.
I couldn't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Hint: which of Maxwell’s equations tells you about divergence of E field, and what needs to be there for it to be nonzero?

Comment: In English, only capitalize the first word of each sentence, names, and the word "I". English is not like German.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the derivations for wave equation of non linear optical media are done assuming, charge-free and current-free conditions, in which case $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = 0$.

I am sure the general wave equation will have source term accounting for the presence of charge or current:

$$ \nabla^2 \mathbf{E} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2} = \mu_0\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{P}_{NL}}{\partial t^2},$$ where the $\mathbf{P}_{NL}$ is a non-linear function of $\mathbf{E}$. The term on RHS corresponds to source.